# NGROK keeps changing url from CUSTOM_URL to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost, ngrok

I'm trying to display a wordpress site to a customer using ngrok.

I tried using different comments.

first of: `ngrok.exe http 80` this works i see the folder where all my sites are in.

```
Ngrok
  website 1
  website 2
  website 3
```

but when i target my wordpress website the domain changes to localhost/website1
making it impossible for the customer to see his website.

i tried setting the root of my wordpress to my custom ngrok domain. this makes it kinda work, except for the images and assets that cant seem to find their location anymore.

also i tried installing the wordpress plugin (ODT relative urls). this also broke more then it fixed.

I tried using diffrend ngrok comments, they worked but didn't change a thing.

If it is any help, i use xampp to make my files to a localhost server.

```
in short -
```

ngrok display localhost/WEBSITE instead of the desired NGROK_LINK/WEBSITE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was wordpress home url was set to localhost, when loading the new url it redirected back to localhost from the database wordpress home property.

Comment: Hi there, how did you solve this? I have the same problem. Using ngrok just shows a list of all the sites i run on my localhost. when i click on the site i want to share, nothing happens. It seems like it's trying to load it but never gets there.

Comment: I solved it by using a subdomain of my own website to save some hassle. You have to set the base url in your wordpress settings and in the database. Else it will try to redirect to the wrong pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but you can also do this with a simple change to the wp-config file.

Comment out these lines:

```
//define('WP_HOME','http://localhost');
//define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');
```

And add these:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://YOURNGROKURL.io');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://YOURNGROKURL.io');
```

Once you're done testing, switch it back to return things to normal.